# LLVM: Retrieving the value of constant function parameters from the C++ API

Tags: c++, llvm

I am writing some code using the LLVM API. I am using the llvm::CallGraph object to loop through all of the child functions called by a parent function:

```
CallGraph cg( *mod );
for( auto i = cg.begin(); i != cg.end(); ++i )
{
    const Function *parent = i->first;
    if( !parent )
        continue;

    for( auto j = i->second->begin(); j != i->second->end(); ++j )
    {
        Function *child = j->second->getFunction();
        if( !child )
            continue;
        for( auto iarg = child->arg_begin(); iarg != child->arg_end(); ++iarg )
        {
            // Print values here!
        }
    }
    o.flush();
```

The actual function call in the IR that I'm interested in looks like this:

`call void @_ZN3abc3FooC1Ejjj(%"struct.abc::Foo"* %5, i32 4, i32 2, i32 0)`

and what I'd like to do is retrieve those last three constant integer values: 4, 2, 0. Bonus points if I can retrieve the %5 as well, but it's not as important. I've spent about two hours staring at http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/ but I simply can't figure out how I'm supposed to get those three values out.

Answer (score 3):

In your second loop, when you iterate over the `CallGraphNode`, you get back instances of `std::pair<WeakVH, CallGraphNode*>`. The `WeakVH` represents the calling instruction, while the `CallGraphNode*` represents the called function. The problem with the code you have is that you're looking at the called function and iterating over the formal parameters in its definition instead of looking at the call site. You want something like this instead (n.b. I haven't tested this, just going off the signatures):

```
CallGraph cg( *mod );
for( auto i = cg.begin(); i != cg.end(); ++i )
{
    for( auto j = i->second->begin(); j != i->second->end(); ++j )
    {
        CallSite CS(*j->first);
        for (auto arg = CS.arg_begin(); arg != CS.arg_end(); ++arg) {
            // Print values here!
        }
    }
    o.flush();
```

From there you can get at the `Value*` pointers representing the arguments, check if they're `ConstantInt`, etc.

Comment: That's a great start; I'd love to know how to check if a Value* is a ConstantInt, etc? Do I just dyn_cast to ConstantInt and see if it worked?

Comment: @AHelps Yes, the typical thing is to write e.g. `if (ConstantInt *CI = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(*arg)) {`